# recover ETH transferred to ETC wallet

Tags: wallets, private-key, recovery, backup

I have mistakenly transferred ETH to ETC wallet from Binance to Kucoin as I have gone through the reviews & noticed that I can only recover my ETH through Kucoin & there is no other way i can retrieve them.

However I have spoken to the representative & firstly they said that it cannot be done & there is no way out, then i sent them few links on which different people has posted that it can recovered if we can get the private key but Kucoin is not providing me with that says that it has private information of the user & after insisting a lot they took the details from me such as TXID & screen shots of my wallets & said that we cannot guarantee & will take 2 months so i have a question

- Does the procedure takes that much of time or i will be considered in the Queue?
- Every private key of the assets differs from every users or it is the same for everyone??
- All over internet it says that assets of same fork can be recovered if transfer into the same fork like ETC & ETH is of the same fork!

Hopefully anyone will revert because if i can retrieved it with your help would really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi there. Yes, it's _technically_ possible, but it will depend on whether the exchange is willing or able to do it. (Some exchanges charge a fee for such recovery.) You'll need to continue your dialogue with Kucoin, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi 

Thanks for responding to my post, 

I have spoken to few of them & they say that it is possible to do so but at the same time i have gone through the reviews which says that kucoin is not willing to recover or return the assets, maybe they can recover & don't return them to the user's do you think there is a chance of that?

& every user has the same private key for the wallet or it differs to each other? 

Best regards

Comment: Hi @Danish - that's interesting to know. You might want to publicise their lack of help on their Reddit page, and see if the bad press changes their minds. It could be that they're extremely busy at the minute and can't actually spend the time to do it. Don't give up yet, keep pestering them.

Answer (score 1):

The private key should be possible be retrieve, However depending on their wallet implementation it could be easy or really hard to do so, for any address (not considering ETH, ETC forks).

Some exchanges have procedures for such incidents, some other may need further follow ups from the user to escalate the issue to their development team.

Kucoin can possibly access the funds sent to that address, however it might not be as easy as accessing private keys in a personal wallet.